# Same Variable, different result

Tags: c#

I just started out learning c# and I came across something confusing, I hope someone can explain it to me :)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int Md = 0;

        private void cmdAnzeigen1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            Md = Md + 1;
            x = x + 1;
            lblErgebnis.Text = "x: " + x + "\n" + "Gx:" + Md;       
        }
    }
}
```

How come `Md` always increases by 1, but `x` doesn't (stays at 1)? I don't understand, they are both the same variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Md` is an *instance* variable, declared outside any method. It's part of the state of the object, so it "lives" (and maintains its value) for as long as the object is "alive". Different instances of `Form1` would have independent `Md` variables.

`x` is a *local* variable - there's a new variable every time you call the method, and it always starts with a value of 0.

If that isn't enough explanation, please consult a good introductory C# book or tutorial - explaining everything about variables would be a bit much for Stack Overflow, which is more for handling specific problems than learning the fundamentals of a programming language.

Comment: Semantically, the right term for the `Md` symbol isn't a [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)?

Comment: @YairNevet: A field is a kind of variable. So in this case both terms are correct.

Answer (score 1):

x is a local variable. It only exists in the scope of the `cmdAnzeigen1_Click()`-Method. Whenever it is called, x gets freshly initialized with a 0, then incremented. So at the end of the method, it's always 1. The other, however, lives in the scope of the class, it is not reinitialized and keeps it's value for the time the class lives.

Also, look at the code of the method- you declare and initialize the variable anew each iteration. That's how it works: The code in that method will be processed sequentially when it's called, and that initialization doesn't live past the method.

As for [scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx), try something like this and see what happens:

```
int x = 1;
{
    int y = x + 1;
}
int z = x + y;
```

It will throw an error, since the brackets introduce a new scope. Variables from the outer are available to the inner, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

When your method (`cmdAnzeigen1_Click`) has finished executing, then the memory that your `x` variable is using is free'd up ready to be used again elsewhere, as well as any other variables that reside within the method.

The same would happen for your form.

if you had something similar to

```
using(Form1 frm = new Form1()
{
frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then as soon as you leave the using block, the variable `Md`'s place in memory will be free'd up.

`Md` is able to increment as it still holds its place in memory, where as `x` is nolonger required post method

Answer (score 0):

Because MD is class level variable and x is not. On every click x is created and destroyed. But value of Md is retained. Md will retain its value till `Form1` is retained.

Comment: Well it's not really *global* - it's an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the **[scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)** of your variables. MD is declared outside the function scope i.e in Instance scope, therefore it is never re-initialized when you click on button. Whereas x is in the function scope so it is re-initialized to 0 everytime you click on the button.